# Ran fdisk on wrong disk which was part of an LVM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, lvm, fdisk

I wanted to add space to an LVM so added a Virtual disk to my Ubuntu 20.04 Virtual Machine.

The VM already had 3 disks

```
/dev/sda 32.2GB # OS Disk
/dev/sdb 537GB # Data Disk, part of the LVM: Volume_Group_Backup_Repository_500GB
/dev/sdc 537GB # Additional Data disk added earlier to add space to LVM
```

After adding a new disk, below got added:

```
/dev/sde 537GB
```

Somehow, I didn't notice `sde` and came to think that `sdc` is the new disk and ran below commands on it:

```
fdisk /dev/sdc
Command (m for help):n # to create a new partition.
p # to create a primary type of partition.
1 # to create the first partition.
<Enter> # to select default values for the first and last sectors.
t # to change the partition’s system id.
8E # corresponding to the Linux LVM id.
w # to write table to disk.
partprobe # to inform the operating system about partition table changes.
cat /proc/partitions # to verify that the new partition has been created but noticed that there's an /dev/sde also.
```

`/dev/sdc` was part of an LVM named `Volume_Group_Backup_Repository_500GB`.

How do I undo these changes?

Comment: If you ran FDISK and committed the changes (most likely), there is no way to undo the changes.

Comment: I'd start with TestDisk. be sure to never attempt recovery to the disk that the lost partition was on.

Comment: Is there a way to recover the data?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at @John's response I concluded that trying to undo the changes may not be possible.

However, I found that the data in partition was still accessible (possibily because I didn't restart the VM and didn't try to unmount/remount the partition).

So I simply attached a new virtual disk to the VM, created lvm volumes afresh and the moved the data to this new volume. After ensuring that all data was correctly copied, removed the old disk.

Thanks @john and @frank-thomas for comments.

Comment: Glad it all worked out for you! I know you were looking for a yes/no answer, but the fact of the matter is, that with data recovery there is NEVER a solid "Yes". there are lots of absolute "No's", but no guarantees of success.